# Liferay : Configuring Multiple Spring MVC Portlets in one liferay plugin project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liferay-6, spring-portlet-mvc

I am developing Spring MVC based portlet in liferay. Basically I want to configure and maintain 2 or 3 portlets in a single liferay project itself. Can some on guide me with the configuration required for the same. Like config code for portlet.xml, spring config and web config (if its required). I just need to configure a default controller for all my portlets separately so each will land in different landing page.

Does anybody know how to config these portlets ? Any suggestions would be helpful :D

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, its possible to configure multiple spring portlets in a single plugin project in such a way that single .war file contains multiple portlets.

**In web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>view-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>view-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**In applicationContext.xml**

You can specify common bean configuration for all portlets here.

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="cache" value="false"/>
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

**In portlet.xml**

You can specify multiple entries of <portlet> in this file. For spring portlet, you should specify <portlet-class> and <init-param> as below.

```
    <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
        <value>classpath:myportlet-context.xml</value>
    </init-param>
```

**In myportlet-context.xml**

Place your portlet controller classes in my.portlet.package and specify it in this file.

> <context:component-scan base-package="my.portlet.package" />

**In liferay-portlet.xml**

Even this file contains multiple <portlet> tags.

**In Your portlet controller class**

Add annotations to specify controller and to map with portlet mode. You can see here various other mappings available in spring documentation.

> @Controller
>
> @RequestMapping(value = PortletModeVal.VIEW)
>
> public class MyPortletControll implements PortletConfigAware